# the Space of fraction and equation looks strange

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

[image]

the LaTeX code is:

```
$Z_c$ :
$$
\begin{equation} \tag{3}
Z_c=\sqrt{\frac{R_0+jωL_0}{G_0+jωC_0}}
\end{equation}
$$$$
\begin{equation} \tag{4}
I^+=\dfrac{U^+}{Z_c} \quad I^-=\dfrac{U^-}{Z_c}
\end{equation}
$$
```

My problem: 1. the R0+jωL0 in first fraction is too close to the top edge of square root line
2. The superscript of plus and minus characters are too big (I+, I-, U+, U-).

New to LaTeX, have no idea to solve this, please help me, thanks too much.

Comment: You must get multiple errors from that? You should never use `$$` in latex but `equation`  can not be used inside math mode so here you need to delete all four `$$`

Comment: Thanks! I think those issues are related to my develop environment, searching for another editor is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

The input suggested produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{equation}
                     \tag{3}
```

Note that after an error tex tries to "recover" so it can check more of the document but it does not try to produce sensible typeset output.

If I fix the syntax error and use a multi-line math display as you should not have adjacent display math environments, I get

[image]

(with lualatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$Z_c$ :
\begin{gather}
Z_c=\sqrt{\frac{R_0+jωL_0}{G_0+jωC_0}}\\
I^+=\frac{U^+}{Z_c} \quad I^-=\frac{U^-}{Z_c}
\end{gather}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The omegas are missing; I think the OP is using `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg oops will fix, OP could have mentioned that:-)

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome!  I think those issues are related to my develop environment, searching for another editor is preferred. BTW, your comments inspired me that the `\omega` can be alternation for ω